# How to use react hook in specific NextJS? (Firebase Authentication)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a nextjs app. I want to authenticate users with firebase. But I want some pages to client-side render and some pages to server-side render. But When I am using this Hook in _app.tsx all pages are rendered on the client side.

**How can I use this hook on a specific page so that only that page renders on the client side?**

**_app.tsx**

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UserAuthContentProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout></UserAuthContentProvider>
  );
}
```

**AuthContext Hook**

```
export const auth = getAuth(app);
const AuthContext = createContext<any>({});
export const useAuthContextProvider = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const UserAuthContentProvider = ({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isUserAuthenticated, setIsUserAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                setUser(user);
                setIsUserAuthenticated(true);
            } else {
                setUser(null);
                setIsUserAuthenticated(false);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    });
};

const signUp = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((result) => {
        if (!result.user.emailVerified) {
            router.push("/verification");
        } else {
            router.push("/dashboard");
        }
    });
};

const logIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((result) => {
        if (!result.user.emailVerified) {
            router.push("/verification");
        } else {
            router.push("/dashboard");
        }
    });
};

const logOut = async () => {
    setUser(null);
    await auth.signOut().finally(() => {
        router.push("/");
    });
};

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
            user,
            logIn,
            signUp,
            logOut,
            isUserAuthenticated,
        }}
    >
        {loading ? null : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: Add logic in `UserAuthContentProvider` to check the current page, and not conditionally render the `children` in `{loading ? null : children}`. That's what making _all_ pages render on the client-side only.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the NextJS Data Fetching docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview) they go over which hook to use to trigger which pages you want to render and where.

If you want certain pages to server render you use `getServerSideProps` if you want to do a regular React runtime client render you can use `getInitialProps` and if you want to Static Site Generate at server build time you use `getStaticProps`. Depending on which hook you use on which Page is what determines the NextJS rendering strategy.

In development mode NextJS always uses SSR for developer experience so if you want to test you will need to run `npm run build && npm run start`.

If you only want a certain page to do one of the rending strategies maybe you can put the rending hook with the strategy you want as a noop on that page.

Since that hook is in the _app it will always run during all strategies so the pages always have that data hydrated. Depending on the strategy will depend on how often that data updates or when its referenced during the build cycle.

Comment: Is there any other way without using useEffect to pass context to the required components?